# Error in formula field of crystal reports when no records found

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working on crystal reports. 
I want to show the sum of the record on footer of every page.
so I have added the formula field in crystal reports which have below formula.

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar PageTotl;

if isNULL({Customer.PaidAmount})Then 
0
else
PageTotl:=PageTotl + {Customer.PaidAmount}
```

its gives error below when there are no records present with given criteria.

[image]

What kind of changes I have to made in above code, so it can also handle the  0 records.

Comment: Actually I have checked and isnull should work without any problem... can you tell if there is no data means are tables and field present in that case?

Comment: Well, there is no records...ex. If I try to find the records from 15 Dec 2016 to 20 Dec 2016 then it shows this error, as there is no record exist of this date. I want to handle this kind of error.

Comment: Actually I have tried your condition at my side.. suprisingly didn't face any issue

Comment: Hope you have declared numbervar PageTotl; and you have no records for this condition....

Comment: Check under Report Options -> Convert Database values to null option is checked. This will confirm that empty values are converted to null  so that isNUll could handle it. Alternatively put 2 hardcoded strings under each condition and see which one prints in this case.

Comment: How are you assigning the data to your report? Is it a dataset, a datatable or are you retrieving data directly from your report? If it's a dataset or a datatable, then check if the datasource has rows, if not, show a message that there are no records and do no open the report.

Comment: Can we have your request? Prefer use a linq query or SQL View. It's better to separate datas and visualization. And This is in your query you can change null in otherthings (**Case when** in SQL or **if(Condition,TruePart,FalsePart)** in linq) It's just example

Comment: Does the report work properly if there is records that exist for the chosen filters?

Comment: I faced this problem with DataSet not typed. If you are using a DataSet, check if the column PaidAmount has an explicit type.

Comment: Are you sure that when there are values it is giving you results?

Answer (score 2):

First, I got the same error, After fixing the formula to the following one, no errors came out:

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar PageTotl;

if isNULL({Customer.PaidAmount})Then 
0
else
PageTotl:=PageTotl + ToNumber({Customer.PaidAmount})
```